# Where do I set the tls-key, tls-cert flags for influxd service for influx V2.4?

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

Docs suggest to start the influxd service with influxd with the flags --tls-key --tls-cert to prevent this error

```
influx ping
Error: Get "https://localhost:8086/health": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

I have created the keys and added the following in /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

```
bind-address = "127.0.0.1:8088"
tls-cert="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt"
tls-key="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key"
```

I am still getting the same error. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't uninstall influx v 1.x when I was upgrading. Uninstalled and reinstalled and it works.